# How to sort a List/ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a List of doubles in java and I want to sort ArrayList in descending order.

Input ArrayList is as below:

```
List<Double> testList = new ArrayList();

testList.add(0.5);
testList.add(0.2);
testList.add(0.9);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.54);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.92);
testList.add(0.12);
testList.add(0.65);
testList.add(0.34);
testList.add(0.62);
```

The out put should be like this

```
0.92
0.9
0.71
0.71
0.71
0.65
0.62
0.54
0.5
0.34
0.2
0.12
0.1
0.1
0.1
```

Comment: testList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

Answer (score 673, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(testList);
Collections.reverse(testList);
```

That will do what you want. Remember to import `Collections` though!

[Here is the documentation for `Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that you can define your own `Comparator` :)

Comment: @Polygnome The OP is only sorting `Double`s.

Comment: Yes, but you could sort them in various ways, depending on the use case. Sometimes you might want to sort them by distance to 0. I don't even know about the runtime characteristics of `reverse`, but sorting descending could actually be faster then sorting ascending and then reversing. Moreover, using a List implementation that  supports `Comparator` as constructor argument (thus keeping it invariant) would ensure the list is sorted at all times.

Comment: Old post of course, but to sort a list of objects, one must have a CompareTo method defined, similar to using Arrays.sort, I assume?

Comment: @Ayesha Yes, `Collections.sort` uses `compareTo` behind the scenes.

Comment: One should actually use `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());`. Apart from being more idiomatic (and possibly more efficient), using the reverse order comparator makes sure that the sort is *stable* (meaning that the order of elements will not be changed when they are equal according to the comparator, whereas reversing will change the order).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this sort IS case sensitive. Uppercase A-Z then lowercase a-z

Comment: In 2019, this answer is harfmul and outdated. Don't do this!

Comment: What about sorting array?

Comment: @Jack - you can use java.util.Arrays.sort(arr)

Answer (score 181):

Descending:

```
Collections.sort(mArrayList, new Comparator<CustomData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CustomData lhs, CustomData rhs) {
        // -1 - less than, 1 - greater than, 0 - equal, all inversed for descending
        return lhs.customInt > rhs.customInt ? -1 : (lhs.customInt < rhs.customInt) ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: What should I do if `CustomData ` is `List<AnotherModel>` which `AnotherModel` has `id` and I want to sort by `id`? And I just access to `CustomData ` model in my class.

Comment: You'd just replace the CustomData class with AnotherModel and have a line like this :   return lhs.id > rhs.id ? -1 : .. etc

Comment: The compare return statement can be better written as `Integer.compare(rhs.customInt, lhs.customInt);`

Answer (score 158):

For your example, this will do the magic in Java 8

```
List<Double> testList = new ArrayList();
testList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

But if you want to sort by some of the fields of the object you are sorting, you can do it easily by:

```
testList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ClassName::getFieldName));
```

or

```
 testList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ClassName::getFieldName).reversed());
```

or

```
 testList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(ClassName::getFieldName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sources:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Where is 'comparing'-method located?

Comment: you need to import: import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Comment: It is available with Java 1.7?

Comment: No, this is a part of stream and functional interface, which is all part of Java 8

Comment: What type is your `testList`? I can't see a zero-arg `sort()` on `List<>` or `Iterable<>`.

Comment: You are right @AjahnCharles. They have removed zero-arg, so I have updated my answer now.

Comment: @krmanish007 - `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is a welcome replacement!! Good knowledge :)

Comment: What's great about the `testList.stream().sorted` is that it creates a sorted _copy_ of the list in a single line. This is handy if you don't want to change the order of the original list

Comment: The `stream()` example requires `.collect(Collectors.toList())` at the end to complete the operation.

Comment: you are right @JonathanBenn, but I am not returning any particular type, so in this case, it will return stream. My idea was to show the different ways of doing the sorting on a list. Regarding your comment about `testList.stream().sorted`, it is more useful if you are doing a few other operations other than sorting, then you can open a stream and do it together, rather than doing it in two different operations.

Answer (score 95):

Use util method of [java.util.Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class, i.e

```
Collections.sort(list)
```

In fact, if you want to sort custom object you can use

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

see collections api

Comment: What about sorting array?

Answer (score 68):

Using lambdas (Java 8), and stripping it down to the barest of syntax (the JVM will infer *plenty* in this case), you get:

```
Collections.sort(testList, (a, b) -> b.compareTo(a));
```

A more verbose version:

```java
// Implement a reverse-order Comparator by lambda function
Comparator<Double> comp = (Double a, Double b) -> {
    return b.compareTo(a);
};

Collections.sort(testList, comp);
```

The use of a lambda is possible because the Comparator interface has only a single method to implement, so the VM can infer which method it's implementing. Since the types of the params can be inferred, they don't need to be stated, i.e. `(a, b)` instead of `(Double a, Double b)`. And since the lambda body has only a single line, and the method is expected to return a value, the `return` is inferred and the braces aren't necessary.

Comment: This is cool, thanks!

This one is a bit more compact:

Collections.sort(testList, Comparator.reverseOrder());

Comment: Even more compact: testList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

Comment: You don't need the compareTo as well. `Collections.sort(testList, (a, b) -> b - a);` will achieve the same result

Answer (score 34):

Here is a short cheatsheet that covers typical cases:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

// sort
list.sort(naturalOrder());

// sort (reversed)
list.sort(reverseOrder());

// sort by field
list.sort(comparing(Type::getField));

// sort by field (reversed)
list.sort(comparing(Type::getField).reversed());

// sort by int field
list.sort(comparingInt(Type::getIntField));

// sort by double field (reversed)
list.sort(comparingDouble(Type::getDoubleField).reversed());

// sort by nullable field (nulls last)
list.sort(comparing(Type::getNullableField, nullsLast(naturalOrder())));

// two-level sort
list.sort(comparing(Type::getField1).thenComparing(Type::getField2));
```

Comment: What about sorting array?

Answer (score 32):

With Java8 there is a default sort method on the List interface that will allow you to sort the collection if you provide a Comparator.  You can easily sort the example in the question as follows:

```
testList.sort((a, b) -> Double.compare(b, a));
```

Note: the args in the lambda are swapped when passed in to Double.compare to ensure the sort is descending

Comment: To me this is the best answer as it also works for sorting using objects ... example 
`locationDetails.sort((locationDetailAsc,locationDetailsDsc) ->
                            Long.compare(locationDetailsDsc.getSnapshot().getQuantity(),
                                    locationDetailAsc.getSnapshot().getQuantity()));`

Comment: what type of sort does this method perform?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `Collections.sort(list)` to sort `list` if your `list` contains `Comparable` elements. Otherwise I would recommend you to implement that interface like here:

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {}
```

and of course provide your own realization of `compareTo` method like here:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Circle another) {
        if (this.getD()<another.getD()){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

And then you can again use `Colection.sort(list)` as now list contains objects of Comparable type and can be sorted. Order depends on `compareTo` method. Check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html for more detailed information.

Answer (score 12):

`Collections.sort` allows you to pass an instance of a `Comparator` which defines the sorting logic. So instead of sorting the list in natural order and then reversing it, one can simply pass `Collections.reverseOrder()` to `sort` in order to sort the list in reverse order:

```
// import java.util.Collections;
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

As mentioned by @Marco13, apart from being more idiomatic (and possibly more efficient), using the reverse order comparator makes sure that the sort is stable (meaning that the order of elements will not be changed when they are equal according to the comparator, whereas reversing will change the order)

Answer (score 9):

```
//Here is sorted List alphabetically with syncronized

package com.mnas.technology.automation.utility;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * @author manoj.kumar
 */
public class SynchronizedArrayList {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SynchronizedArrayList.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Employee>());
        synchronizedList.add(new Employee("Aditya"));
        synchronizedList.add(new Employee("Siddharth"));
        synchronizedList.add(new Employee("Manoj"));
        Collections.sort(synchronizedList, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object synchronizedListOne, Object synchronizedListTwo) {
                //use instanceof to verify the references are indeed of the type in question
                return ((Employee) synchronizedListOne).name
                        .compareTo(((Employee) synchronizedListTwo).name);
            }
        }); 
    /*for( Employee sd : synchronizedList) {
    log.info("Sorted Synchronized Array List..."+sd.name);
    }*/

        // when iterating over a synchronized list, we need to synchronize access to the synchronized list
        synchronized (synchronizedList) {
            Iterator<Employee> iterator = synchronizedList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                log.info("Sorted Synchronized Array List Items: " + iterator.next().name);
            }
        }

    }
}

class Employee {
    String name;

    Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }
}
```

Comment: seems to be thas is Collections.synchronizedList helps us

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.sort(yourList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Collection has a default Comparator that can help you with that.

Also, if you want to use some Java 8 new features, you can do like that:

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
yourList = yourList.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Java SE 8, then this might be of help.

```
//create a comparator object using a Lambda expression
Comparator<Double> compareDouble = (d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2);

//Sort the Collection in this case 'testList' in reverse order
Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder(compareDouble));

//print the sorted list using method reference only applicable in SE 8
testList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: There is also `Collections.reverseOrder()` without any arguments, which makes your implementation of `compareDouble` superfluous (it's equivalent to the natural ordering of `Double`s). The answer here should be `Collections.sort(testList, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Answer (score 5):

|*| Sorting an List :

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

|=> Sort Asc Order :

```
Collections.sort(NamAryVar);
```

|=> Sort Dsc Order :

```
Collections.sort(NamAryVar, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

---

|*| Reverse the order of List :

```
Collections.reverse(NamAryVar);
```

Answer (score 5):

In JAVA 8 its much easy now.

```
List<String> alphaNumbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
List<String> alphaNumbersUpperCase = alphaNumbers.stream()
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(alphaNumbersUpperCase); // [FOUR, ONE, THREE, TWO]
```

-- For reverse use this

```
.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use like that

```
ArrayList<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(groupList, Collections.reverseOrder());
Collections.reverse(groupList);
```

Answer (score 3):

For example I have a class Person: String name, int age ==>Constructor new Person(name,age)

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public void main(String[] args){
    Person ibrahima=new Person("Timera",40);
    Person toto=new Person("Toto",35);
    Person alex=new Person("Alex",50);
    ArrayList<Person> myList=new ArrayList<Person>
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            // return p1.age+"".compareTo(p2.age+""); //sort by age
            return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name); // if you want to short by name
        }
    });
    System.out.println(myList.toString());
    //[Person [name=Alex, age=50], Person [name=Timera, age=40], Person [name=Toto, age=35]]
    Collections.reverse(myList);
    System.out.println(myList.toString());
    //[Person [name=Toto, age=35], Person [name=Timera, age=40], Person [name=Alex, age=50]]

}
```

Comment: `if you want to short by name` -> `if you want to sort by name`

Answer (score 3):

If you have to sort object based on its id in the ArrayList , then use java8 stream.

```java
 List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Person> personListSorted =
                personList.stream()
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getPersonId))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you could create a primitive double list, sort it and then reverse it to put it in descending order.  This approach would avoid boxing the doubles.

```
MutableDoubleList doubleList =
    DoubleLists.mutable.with(
        0.5, 0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.54, 0.71,
        0.71, 0.71, 0.92, 0.12, 0.65, 0.34, 0.62)
        .sortThis().reverseThis();
doubleList.each(System.out::println);
```

**Updated:** Sept. 2023

Since the 10.3 release, [Eclipse Collections supports indirect sorting of primitive lists](https://medium.com/javarevisited/eclipse-collections-now-supports-indirect-sorting-of-primitive-lists-e2447ca5dbc3).

```
@Test
public void sortDoubleListInDescendingOrder()
{
    MutableDoubleList testList = DoubleLists.mutable
            .with(0.5, 0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.54, 0.71, 0.71,
                  0.71, 0.92, 0.12, 0.65, 0.34, 0.62);

    DoubleList expected = DoubleLists.mutable
            .with(0.92, 0.9, 0.71, 0.71, 0.71, 0.65, 0.62, 0.54,
                  0.5, 0.34, 0.2, 0.12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

    Assertions.assertNotEquals(expected, testList);

    testList.sortThis((i, j) -> -Double.compare(i, j));

    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, testList);
}
```

**End Update**

If you want a `List<Double>`, then the following would work.

```
List<Double> objectList =
    Lists.mutable.with(
        0.5, 0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.54, 0.71,
        0.71, 0.71, 0.92, 0.12, 0.65, 0.34, 0.62)
        .sortThis(Collections.reverseOrder());
objectList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to keep the type as `ArrayList<Double>`, you can initialize and sort the list using the `ArrayListIterate` utility class as follows:

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayList =
    ArrayListIterate.sortThis(
            new ArrayList<>(objectList), Collections.reverseOrder());
arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 0):

The following line should do the thick

```
testList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  yearList = arrayListOf()
    for (year in 1950 until 2021) {
        yearList.add(year)
    }

   yearList.reverse()
    val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

    for (year in yearList) {
        list.add(year.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to order a List is using the Collections framework;

in this case using the SortedSet (the bean in the list should implement Comparable, so Double is ok):

```
List<Double> testList;
...
SortedSet<Double> sortedSet= new TreeSet<Double>();
for(Double number: testList) {
   sortedSet.add(number);
}
orderedList=new ArrayList(sortedSet);
```

In general, to order by an attribute of a bean in the list,put all the elements of the list in a SortedMap, using as a key the attribute, then get the values() from the SortedMap (the attribute should implement Comparable):

```
List<Bean> testList;
...
SortedMap<AttributeType,Bean> sortedMap= new TreeMap<AttributeType, Bean>();
for(Bean bean : testList) {
   sortedMap.put(bean.getAttribute(),bean);
}
orderedList=new ArrayList(sortedMap.values());
```