# How can I sort a List of Pair<String,Integer>?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a list of commmons `Pair` that stores words and their frequency like the following

```
private List<Pair<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>();
```

I am trying to sort it so that when I iterate over it to print the words, I want the words with the highest frequency to appear first.

I tried playing around with implementing `Comparable` but most examples are not similar to using a list of Pairs

Comment: You should be able to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-list-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Don't you think it's better to define a `Pair` class with word and its frequency instead of using the `Pair` structure from commons. That way you can simply create a custom `Comparator` to define the sorting criteria based on the word (or) frequency

Comment: Why don't you use a Map? Map<String, Integer> wordsFrequencyMap;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Pair<String, Integer> o1, final Pair<String, Integer> o2) {
        // TODO: implement your logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 25):

To sort the elements by decreasing order of number

```
Collections.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(p -> -p.getRight()));
```

This will use the "right" of the pair in descending order.

This uses Java 8. Notionally you are boxing the value and using Integer.compareTo.

However, with escape analysis, the boxing can be eliminated and you mgiht not be creating any objects.

Comment: will this unbox or use Integer compareTo?

Comment: What does the hyphen before p mean?

Comment: @DesertScuba it's a negative operator. It reverses the order. ie. 3 < 5 but -3 > -5

Answer (score 3):

Hello i think this should work for you.

```
 List<Pair<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
    words.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("hello",2));
    words.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("hello",1));
    words.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("aello",3));

    words.sort(new Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<String, Integer> o1, Pair<String, Integer> o2) {
            if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getValue().equals(o2.getValue())) {
                return 0; // You can change this to make it then look at the
                          //words alphabetical order
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println(words);
```

Comment: don't you think that relying on compareTo() provided by Integer would be better instead of rewriting it yourself?

Comment: Sure but if you want to further sort the values alphabetically if the frequency is the same then it doesnt make much difference . But if you aren't, returning Integer.compare(o1.getValue() ,o2.getValue()); is easier yes.

Comment: @GregKing Or you _could_ use [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-). Depends how much redundant code you want to write I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Java 8 lambda in combination with `Comparator.comparing` (you also need to reverse the order):

```
import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

final List<Pair<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<>();
final Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>> c = reverseOrder(comparing(Pair::getValue));
Collections.sort(words, c);
```

Easiest way if you just want to print the values in descending order of frequency:

```
words.stream()
        .sorted(c)
        .map(Pair::getKey)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```