# How to use UNION ALL in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

my question is how i perform UNION ALL clause in JPA ?
is it possible to use @NamedQuery? this query using 2 tables at a time in each SELECT statement and at the end it is using ORDER BY

```
    SELECT 0 as intorder, u.id, q.order_type
      FROM test_union u, test_query q
     WHERE u.id     = q.id
       AND u.type   is NULL
       AND q.field1 = 'DEFAULTS'
UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as intorder, u.id, q.order_type
      FROM test_union u, test_query q
     WHERE u.id     = q.id
       AND u.type   is NOT NULL
       AND q.field1 = 'TESTING'
 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as intorder, u.id, q.order_type
      FROM test_union u, test_query q
     WHERE u.id     = q.id
       AND u.type   is NULL
       AND q.field1 = 'DEFAULTS'
ORDER BY intorder, q.order_type;
```

Comment: you don't. there is no such thing in JPQL.

Comment: so is there any way to do this in jpa?

Comment: JPA allows you to use SQL queries, and then you throw away database independence.

Comment: is it possible in HQL ?

Comment: No idea. JPA does not do "HQL"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Jpql and Hql (one is the subset of the other,  and JPA uses Jpql) are not supporting **UNION**, you would need to use native queries suited to your database query language. An implementation could look like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="EntityClassName.functionName"
    , query="SELECT .. "
        + "UNION ALL "
        + "SELECT .."
    , resultClass=YourResultClass.class`
)
```

directly on one of your entities and in your repository interface:

```
public interface EntityClassNameRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityClassName, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<YourResultClass> functionName(parameter list)
```

When I was doing something equal `YourResultClass` needed to be an entity.

Another solution would be to extract the UNION out of the database into the JVM, where multiple query results enhance a list. Afterward the list also could be sorted ([How to sort a ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-arraylist-in-java)).

Answer (score 0):

Use each query separately. like

```
SELECT 0 as intorder, u.id, q.order_type
      FROM test_union u, test_query q
     WHERE u.id     = q.id
       AND u.type   is NULL
       AND q.field1 = 'DEFAULTS'
```

then you can pass each queries separately, then you can merge these result in to one result.

Comment: It would be hectic if there is a pagination implementation on top of these repositories.