# Unable to sort. How to sort a list of objects by name?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I want to sort childRequirementGroupControllers which is a list of RequirementGroupController, but it is not allowing me to do. Syntactically, what am I doing wrong?

```
private List<RequirementGroupController> childRequirementGroupControllers = new ArrayList<RequirementGroupController>();

@Override
public void requirementAdded(Requirement requirement)
{   
    Collections.sort(childRequirementGroupControllers, (RequirementGroupController a1,
                    RequirementGroupController a2) -> a1.getRequirementGroup.getName() - a2.getRequirementGroup.getName());
}
```

Inside RequirementGroup Controller I have:

```
public class RequirementGroupController extends BaseController
{
  public Requirement getRequirementGroup()
  {
    return requirementGroup;
  }

}
```

Which contains a Requirement class and  I finally want to sort by Requirement.getName().

Comment: google: Comparator, Comparable and such

Comment: @Stultuske I did. I looked at other examples of Collections sorting and still can not figure this one out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Assuming that `getName()` returns a `String`, you are trying to subtract them.  `-` is not defined for strings.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [`String#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) to sort the object within the ArrayList by their names.

```
Collections.sort(childRequirementGroupControllers, (a1, a2) -> a1.getRequirementGroup.getName().compareTo(a2.getRequirementGroup.getName()));
```

note that I didn't explicitly specify the argument types when using the lambda expression as this is inferred from the context.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subtract a `String` from another.  A proper way to do it with Java 8 would be the following:

```
Collections.sort(childRequirementGroupControllers, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getRequirementGroup.getName()));
```

Comment: When I try this it's saying "The type RequirementGroupController does not define getName(T) that is applicable here"

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that `RequirementGroupController` did not implement a `getName` method.  I'd use @Aominè's answer

Comment: You can still use `Comparator.comparing(controller -> controller.getRequirementGroup().getName())`