# Sort ArrayList reverse without implementing any method by user?

Tags: java

```
   import java.util.*;
    public class Details  {

        public static void main(String args[]){
           ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
           arraylist.add("AA");
           arraylist.add("ZZ");
           arraylist.add("CC");
           arraylist.add("FF");


           System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
           for(String str: arraylist){
                System.out.println(str);
            }

           /* Sorting in decreasing order*/

        }
    }
```

Now how would I do this? Im new in this field. If this stupid then I would delete it but please help me I really need this to be answered.

Comment: Answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.*; public class Details {
  public static void main(String args[]){
     ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
     arraylist.add("AA");
     arraylist.add("ZZ");
     arraylist.add("CC");
     arraylist.add("FF");


     System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
     for(String str: arraylist){
          System.out.println(str);
      }

     /* Sorting in decreasing order*/
     Collections.sort(arraylist);
     Collections.reverse(arraylist);
     for(String str: arraylist){
          System.out.println(str);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how to sort it normally?

Comment: By only Collections.sort(arraylist);

Comment: `arrayList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed())`. Both nearter and faster - doesn't require another pass to reverse.

Comment: I never think that way!! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 8, `List` has a [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method that takes a `Comparator` parameter.
The natural ordering for a list of strings is alphabetic order.
To sort the items of a list in their natural order you can use [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) as the `Comparator`.
To sort the items of a list in the reverse of their natural order,
you can use [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--).

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AA", "ZZ", "CC", "FF");
list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(list);
```

If you are on an older version of Java,
though I don't see a good reason for that,
then you could use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) with [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder()) instead:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AA", "ZZ", "CC", "FF");
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Comparator` before loop:

```
Collections.sort(arraylist , new Comparator<String>() {
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
     return o1.compareTo(o2); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Please consider I want the list in reverse order.

Comment: you can change `o1.compareTo(o2)` to `o2.compareTo(o1)` to descending sorting.

Comment: for reverse you can use `Collections.reverse(arraylist)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
   import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe  {

  public static void main(String args[]){
     ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
     arraylist.add("AA");
     arraylist.add("ZZ");
     arraylist.add("CC");
     arraylist.add("FF");
     Collections.sort(arraylist);


     System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
     for(String str: arraylist){
          System.out.println(str);
      }
     Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
   /* Sorted List in reverse order*/
   System.out.println("ArrayList in descending order:");
   for(String str: arraylist){
        System.out.println(str);
     }
  }
}
```

This will sort it alphabetically then reverse it.