# order cardviews by the number in each cardview

Tags: android

I have currently got it so, when the user presses FAB, a cardview is added to the recyclerview. Inside each cardview is a spinner, eddittext, textview and checkbox.

The spinners are populated by items in one column of a csv. When the user selects an item from the spinner, the coressponding number to the item from the other column in the same csv, shows up in the textview in the same cardview.

So then my app looks like this, the numbers being the textviews.

[image]

**Question** I am wondering if it is possible so that when the the user selects an item from the spinner and the number shows up in the textview, if its possible for the cardviews to automatically sort in order of the number in each cardview? So following the picture above, if it were to be ordered it would be like?

Potato Chips - 0

Coffee - 1

Chocolate - 6

Ice Cream - 14

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();

    private List<Product> productList;

    private Activity create;


    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE


    InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
    CSVFile csvFile = null;


    //TODO END OF CODE FOR CSV FILE

    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity) {
        create = activity;

    }



    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList, Map<String, String> numberList) {
        numberItemValues = numberList;
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(create);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(create, R.layout.item_spinner_layout,
                Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
                mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);

                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);

                String currentItem = holder.spinner.getItemAtPosition(mPosition).toString();

                Set<String> set = numberItemValues.keySet(); for(String key : set) {String value = numberItemValues.get(key);
                    Log.e("DATA ", "key = " + key + " value = " + value); }

                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                holder.textView5.setText(aisleNumber);

                Log.e("SELECTION TEST", " Selected map item = " + aisleNumber );

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        if (mSpinnerSelectedItem.containsKey(position)) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(mSpinnerSelectedItem.get(position));
        }


        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);


                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity


                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                                holder.spinner.setSelection(0);

                                productList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                                Toast.makeText(create, "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public void reset() {


       /* holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.spinner.setSelection(0);*/

        productList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View rootView;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.
                    if(isChecked){

                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        spinner.setSelection(0);

                        productList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());



                        Toast.makeText(create, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });



        }

        public View getView() {
            return rootView;
        }

    }


    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


}
```

**create.java which is my main activity code for the screen where cardviews are added etc**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    Product mProduct;
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


   // RelativeLayout relativeLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);
        findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).requestFocus();







        findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });






        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
         CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

       final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();


        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product(mSpinnerItems, "Test Edit Text",false, "Text String 2"));




        final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, numberItemValues);


        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
             findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productList.add(mProduct);
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });









        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);









    }




    //TODO OVERFLOW MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_delete) {



            ((ProductAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).reset();

            Toast.makeText(create.this,
                    "Shopping List Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }


        if (id == R.id.action_help) {


            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Help");
            builder.setMessage("Click the button in the bottom right corner to add an item. Touch the dropdown menu and begin typing" +
                    "the item you want. The aisle number will then show. You are also able to enter in the quantity you want, for your reference." +
                    "If you made a mistake you can always click the surrounding white box to delete the item. Once you have got the item you" +
                    "can touch the checkbox. If you want to delete your whole list, press the menu button on your device or the 3 dots in the corner and press" +
                    "delete.");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


        }





        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }








    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: yes you can sort them before updating list. and then notify your adapter

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the spinner selection event. When it triggers, you have to reach your collection of data and sort it, after that just notify the adapter `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Are you using recyclerview or ?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) { 
     adapter.sortDataSet();
});
```

In you adapter:

```
public void sortDataSet(){
  //sort dataSet (arrayList, etc)
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Sorting the data is easy. There are plenty of different methods, in one you have to override class methods, in other you have to create additional object or include contract for you class.
You can find a lot of examples here : h

[How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)

If you use java8 i would suggest something like that : 
list.sort((a, b) -> a.field > b.field);

```
class Product implements Comparable<Product> { 
@Override
public int compareTo(Product other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.IntField, other.IntField);
}
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181180/discussion-between-grand-skunk-and-max-aves).