# data structures : quicksort linkedList with java

Tags: java, data-structures, quicksort

is there a way to get the same result when using LinkedList rather than an array? The following code works perfectly, only when Im using array in its generics form. I want to do the same by using LinkedList. so something like this :

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> LinkedList<E> qSort(LinkedList<E> list) {

    return list;
}
```

this is what I already have..

```
 public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] quickSort(E[] list) {
    if (list.length <= 1) {
        return list;
    }
    sort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    return list;
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(E[] list, int low, int high) {

    if ((high - low) <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    int splitPoint = split(list, low, high);
    sort(list, low, splitPoint - 1);
    sort(list, splitPoint + 1, high);
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int split(E[] list, int low, int high) {
    int left = low + 1;
    int right = high;
    E pivot = list[low];
    while (left <= right) {
        if (list[left].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
            left++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true) {

        while (right > left) {
            if (list[right].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                right--;
            }
        }

        if (left >= right) {
            break;
        }

        E temp = list[left];
        list[left] = list[right];
        list[right] = temp;
        left++;
        right--;
    }

    list[low] = list[left -1];
    list[left-1] = pivot;

    return left-1;
}
```

Comment: Unless this is a programming exercise, why not just use [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)?

Comment: please  how can i apply it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16252269/1813169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)

Comment: Do you want to implement the sorting algorith your self for linkedlist using quicksort?

Comment: yes, @efex09 , with array I could do it, but i can't find my way using linkedList as i am new to LinkedList

Comment: This may help https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/vjz17K