# Fetching specified children from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Strucutre]

I am trying to retrieve `Messages/child` sorted on the base of `time`. I have access to `Messages/child`. I am unable to find any useful solution. Please help me figure this out.

My current code is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("Messages")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  @Nullable, String s) {

              Log.d("children",dataSnapshot.getKey());
              users_list.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

          }
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: I am not getting the right way to `Query` ordered by `time`  @SandeepMalik

Comment: What is `I4KN ... A1j2` and `0uo2 ... xWn2`? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: those are the userKeys

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way :-

```
mChatReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        Query query = mChatReference.orderByChild("time");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   Log.d("children",dataSnapshot.getKey());
                users_list.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());            
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: `Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .orderByChild("time");`  when I tried using this, It only returns top level key which is `Messages/key`

Comment: i am only giving the hint to solve your problem add the childs and do your stuff

Comment: it is fully working but its your bad luck ki tum itna sa kam nahi kr pa rhi ho

Comment: I need the data in order with reference to time but it isn't according to my requirements. It is retrieving the data in the existing order.

Comment: ok then keep trying to find the accurate answer to solve your problem but the fact is that all the peoples can give you hint and you have to do it by your own

Comment: just add child in reference and run the code it will work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193240/discussion-between-sandeep-malik-and-nancy).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have a data structure:

```
Messages: {
  uid1: {
    uid2: {
      messageId1: ...
      messageId2: ...
      messageId3: ...
    }
  }
}
```

You attach a `ChildEventListener` to `/Messages/uid1`, which means that your `onChildAdded` gets called for user second-level UID from your JSON. To get to the individual messages, you still need to loop over the child nodes of the `DataSnapshot`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("Messages")
    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  @Nullable, String s) {
              for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  Log.d("message key: ", messageSnapshot.getKey());
                  Log.d("message time: ", messageSnapshot.child("time").getValue(String.class));
              }
          }
```

A few things to note:

- As said, this code loops over the children of the `DataSnapshot` to get to the individual messages.
- Consider storing the data as chat rooms where the key of each chat room is based on the UID of its participants as explained here: [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase)
- You will need to add your messages to a list, and sort them client-side.
- You're storing the time as a display string, which makes it harder to sort them. Consider storing them in a format that is easier to sort, such as `"20190513T073306"` or a timestamp such as `1557758003677`.

Comment: I have changed the timestamp. How am i supposed to sort them in a list? What I wanna do is to bring the person who has the most recent message on the top of the list of users. is this possible by the approach I'm using/?

Comment: I assume that you're adding all messages to a list in a loop, like I've shown in my answer. In that case you can [sort the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist), and then pass it to your adapter.