# sort hashmap value of type list using java 8

Tags: java, arrays

I have a map of String key and Value is List of Strings, I want the List inside the map to be sorted alphabetically, how to do that using java 8

```
K1=[ "Tomato", "potato","Apple"], 
K2=["Plan", "car", "train"]
```

result should be

```
K1=[ "Apple" , "potato","Tomato"], 
K2=["car","Plan", "train"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below function

```
static void sort(Map<String, List<String>> stringListHashMap) {
        stringListHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            Collections.sort(value);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While inserting into Map, sort your list or after retrieve sort your list.
Refer below code for your reference:

```
        Map<String, List<String>> data= new HashMap<>();
        List<String> list1= Stream.of("AAA","CCC","BBB","DDD").sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> list2= Stream.of("CCC","DDD","BBB","AAA").sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        data.put("A",list1.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        data.put("B", list2);
        System.out.println(data);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> yourMap= new HashMap<>();
 List list1 = Arrays.asList("Tomato", "potato","Apple");
 List list2 = Arrays.asList("Plan", "car", "train");
data.put("A",list1.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
data.put("B", list2.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));

This will give you what you are looking for.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeSet as map's value element which keeps values already sorted based on comparator provided.

```
Comparator<? super String> comparator = String::compareToIgnoreCase;

Map<String, TreeSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

TreeSet<String> K1_values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

K1_values.add("Tomato");
K1_values.add("potato");
K1_values.add("Apple");

map.put("K1", K1_values);

TreeSet<String> K2_values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

K2_values.add("Plan");
K2_values.add("car");
K2_values.add("train");

map.put("K2", K2_values);

System.out.println(map);
```

It prints:

```
{K1=[Apple, potato, Tomato], K2=[car, Plan, train]}
```

The items in sorted order as you need.

**Hope this helps!**