# How can I sort a List of <Pair<String, List<class Name>>> in Java?

Tags: java

I have a list of pair

`private List<Pair<String, List<School>> words = new ArrayList<Pair<String, List<School>>();`
Here I have to sort it by no of student in a school.

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem do you run into?

Comment: A bit more explanation will be helpful for the community to understand the problem and help you find the optimal solution. You can consult here for the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) .

Comment: Do you really need list of pairs?
Because List<Pair> = Map, then you can use sorted map

Answer (score 1):

Use `words.sort(comparator)` where `comparator` is instance of your `Comparator<Pair<String, List>>` or lambda.
More information about list sorting: [How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)