# How do i sort objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Just decided to practice some code and i came across this problem. I made the ArrayList to take a list of ten numbers. If I input ten numbers like;
6
0
3
1
8
10
9
2
7
5 ,

It returns the ArrayList;
[6, 0, 3, 1, 8, 10, 9, 2, 7, 5]

How do I return a sorted version of this array, like ascending or descending order? Thanks

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    System.out.println("Enter ten numbers");
    

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      Object ob = sc.nextInt();
      al.add(ob);
    }
    System.out.println(al);

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Collections.sort(al);` before printing.

This method will sort your `ArrayList` for you.

Example in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    System.out.println("Enter ten numbers");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      Object ob = sc.nextInt();
      al.add(ob);
    }
    Collections.sort(al);
    System.out.println(al);

}
```

You can also use `Collections.reverse(al)` after the sort method to change the order or even better, as mentioned by @WJS you can pass `Collections.reverseOrder()` in the sort method in this way: `Collections.sort(al, Collections.reverseOrder())`

Comment: *You can also use Collections.reverse(al) after the sort method to change the order.*  Yes you can but why would you?  Just pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()` to the sort method

Comment: yeah, it's better