# how to sort arraylist of java records

Tags: java, sorting, record

I have a record definition like this:

```
public record UserCourseSubscriptionRec(
    Integer userId,
    String userFirstName,
    String userLastName,
    Integer courseId,
    String courseName,
    Date startDate,
    Date endDate) {
```

}

I have an arrayList of there records.

How can I sort this arrayList by userId ascending then startDate descending?

I know how to do it for a class, but I cannot change this record to a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a List/ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-a-list-arraylist)

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference in sorting between records and plain old classes?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using `LocalDate` and not `Date` as the latter is obsolete, deprecated and buggy.  That and other classes are available in the [java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214525/f1sh) package and offer a wide range of capabilities.

```
public record UserCourseSubscriptionRec(
    Integer userId,
    String userFirstName,
    String userLastName,
    Integer courseId,
    String courseName,
    Date startDate,         
    Date endDate) {
}
```

Define a comparator.

```
Comparator<UserCourseSubscriptionRec> comp = Comparator
                .comparing(UserCourseSubscriptionRec::userId)
                .thenComparing(UserCourseSubscriptionRec::startDate,
                        Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Then use the ArrayList sort method with the comparator.

```
YourList.sort(comp);
```

Or as [f1sh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214525/f1sh) suggested in the comments, you can have your class or record implement the `Comparable` Here interface.  Here is how that might look.

```
record UserCourseSubscriptionRec(Integer userId, String userFirstName,
        String userLastName, Integer courseId, String courseName,
        Date startDate, Date endDate)
        implements Comparable<UserCourseSubscriptionRec> { // implement the interface

    public int compareTo(UserCourseSubscriptionRec ucs) {
        // first, compare the userid's in ascending order
        int result = userId.compareTo(ucs.userId);

        // if non-zero, return the result.
        // otherwise, return the result of sorting in reverse order
        // (changing the `compareTo` argument order reverses the natural order). 
        return result != 0 ? result : 
                ucs.startDate.compareTo(startDate);
               
    }
}
```

Then just call sort as follows. The `null` argument says use the ordering specified by the `Comparable` complementation.

```
YourList.sort(null);
```

Comment: You can also just let the `record` implement `Comparable`.

Comment: That is true.  I will update the answer to mention it.